# Using Php I can't echo out an HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to echo out a php table and something isn't right.
I am trying to echo out information from a table using PDO. I am working through localhost. If someone could tell me what is wrong.

```
<div>

        <?php
        echo "<table>";
        include('connect.php');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts';

        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $posts = $statement->fetchAll();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            echo "<tr><td>". $post['post_title'] . "</td><td>".
                $post['post_body']. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo"</table>";
        ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any basic troubleshooting occurring here

Comment: with <table> taken outside of the loop I see: <div>
<table>
<tr><td>Test Post</td><td>This is a test post</td></tr><tr><td>second post</td><td>here is my post</td></tr></table>
</div>

Comment: yes I am using localhost sorry to forget to metnion

Comment: *"with <table> taken outside of the loop I see: <div> <table> <tr><td>Test Post</td><td>This is a test post</td></tr><tr><td>second post</td><td>here is my post</td></tr></table> </div>"* - So it works then.

Comment: But I am not getting a table displayed.

Comment: Give us the output of `print_r($posts);`

Comment: When I do that I get much:Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_id] => 1 [0] => 1 [post_title] => Test Post [1] => Test Post [post_author] => Matthew [2] => Matthew [post_body] => This is a test post [3] => This is a test post [post_type] => o [4] => o [original_id] => 0 [5] => 0 [forum_name] => 0 [6] => 0 [forum_id] => 0 [7] => 0 [DATETIME] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 [8] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 ) [1] => Array ( [post_id] => 2 [0] => 2 [post_title] => second post [1] => second post [post_author] => matthew [2] => matthew [post_body] => here is my post [3] => here is my post [post_type] => ....

Comment: If you see the table in View Source, but not in the browser, it may be an issue with your CSS or Javascript. Use the browser's Developer Tools to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting to see table cells and forgot that it requires styling to display these.